# Jquery not returning data IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am trying to get a list of classes from an html page using JQuery. I am using the following code:

```
$('.questionsOnPage').each(function () {
    item = {}
    var id = this.id;
    ....
```

This works in all browsers but not IE 10 (I haven't tried older browsers) **But in IE The this.id is null**.

The html looks like this:

```
<div value="23" class="questionsOnPage"><input id="23" class="questionCheckBox"         type="checkbox" />
 ...               
<div value="24" class="questionsOnPage"><input id="24" class="questionCheckBox" type="checkbox" />
 ...
```

Please help if you can

Answer (score 2):

> This works in all browsers but not IE 10

It's not true. It will not work on any other browsers.

`.questionsOnPage` is the div, with no `id`.

The id is on `.questionCheckBox`

And why you put `value` attribute in the div? It's non sense, put it in the `input` element.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it works in other browsers. I think you want to do something like

```
$('.questionsOnPage input').each(function () {
    item = {}
    var id = $(this).id;
    ....
```